# How to define EDI data structure C090

Tags: c#, edi

I am attempting to create an API that will allow me to create and parse EDI messages in C#.

As a proof of concept and to keep it simple I am attempting to write a small class library to create a C090 data structure, which you can see[here](http://www.truugo.com/edifact/d95b/c090/)

I am not sure how it's even possible to create properties for the 3286 data element as there are five of them.  I don't really want to use arrays or lists for this and was wondering if there was any possible way of creating these as five properties, but without bastardizing them with underscores or numbers?

Comment: You're going to run into this with any composite element type.  C080 in the NAD segment is the same way.  You can have up to 5 pieces of information from the source to make up the whole element.  The first subelement is mandatory, per the standard.  I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're trying to do, but it seems to me it shouldn't matter what you name it on the source side (if you're creating the document). Parsing an inbound document is simpler based on delimiters. I think your question can be improved with some sample code of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Andrew I guess you're right that it probably shouldn't matter, but I'd like to try keeping the property names as close as to the original data elements. I think I will try numbering them and see how that goes.

Comment: @mike: disadvantage of numbering is that when a new sub-element is added to a composite numbering goes wrong rest of segment. (is that a problem or is it important? up to your judgment.)

Comment: you might get some idea's for this looking at bots (http://bots.sourceforge.net). In mapping scripts the parsed edi message can be accessed via calls (think that is close to an API?). Similar logic can be used to write edi messages.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find a way of creating the data structure by defining all of the elements of the composite using class attributes.

When calling the `Append(Element)` method it will check the definition to see if `Element` is part of the composite and throws an exception if it isn't, otherwise it will be added to the list, for example:

```
C090 c = doc.CreateComposite<C090>();
E3477 e = doc.CreateElement<E3477>();
e.Value = CodesList.E3477.Code001;
c.Append( e );
```

Seems to work great so far!